# cannot do any installation on ubuntu due to password

Tags: apt, package-management, password, ppa

i am not able to do any installation or updation on ubuntu due the following errors

1. i cannot type my password as it is not accepting when i am typing it. it will msg wrong password type again the password window become static.
2. when i was updating sudo it was giving me the following msg:

Err:6 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/tualatrix/personal/ubuntu jammy Release
404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/tualatrix/personal/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

please help how do i resolve this issue

Comment: PPA's are *personal package archives* which only have the security checks you perform on them yourself, did you do any checks?  A quick look at https://launchpad.net/~tualatrix/+archive/ubuntu/personal (from your question) shows the repository was last used in 2013 thus provides no support for any *modern* Ubuntu, are you attempting to explore security problems?  Remove it asap.

Comment: Apparently you can still login with your password, but if you can't login read this: [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/q/24006/)